# router relay or router bridge

Tags: wireless-networking, router, switch, bridge, relay

i got a dlink wireless router.

i have a client that has two station far from the router, so the connection is slow(10 kbps).

for the netwok to be faster there is a need of a local lan switch.

however im worried that the switch will collide with the wifi dongels.

is there a way to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the D-Link [DAP-1522](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=663) should nicely fit your need. I use one in my house and none of our other wireless devices (two laptops and a Xbox 360) experience any problems.